# Resize NSRunningApplication window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I would like to resize a window i got with the `runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:(pid_t)` function of **NSRunningApplication** class in the the AppKit framework.

Problem is that the NSRunningApplication object does include the `.hide()` and `.unhide()` functions but none to resize the window of the application.

Looking forward to your suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move/resize windows programmatically from another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231110/how-can-i-move-resize-windows-programmatically-from-another-application) or [OSX / Objective-C Window Management: manipulate the frames & visibility of other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010638/osx-objective-c-window-management-manipulate-the-frames-visibility-of-other)

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to adjust the size of the application window. I resized main window container is my app.

With the help of this: window.contentSize/contentMinSize/contentMaxSize

- In visual editor for window:

[image]

- In code:

[image]